# How to select dropdown which doesnot have select tag using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, webdriver

This is the following code and I couldn't use select class to use visible text/index because it doesn't have any select tag.
Here which I got confused is there is one coding for dropdown box and different coding for drodown values.

1) Dropdown box code which can click on it is

```
<div data-aura-rendered-by="16:2348;a">
<a class="select" aria-required="true" aria-disabled="false" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Lead Status" title="" href="javascript:void(0);" data-aura-rendered-by="17:2348;a" data-interactive-lib-uid="8">New</a>
</div>
```

2) Dropdown values code is as below

```
<ul class="scrollable" role="presentation" data-aura-rendered-by="31:2348;a" data-scoped-scroll="true">
<!--render facet: 1770:0-->
<li class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem" role="presentation" data-aura-rendered-by="1774:0" data-aura-class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem">
<li class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem" role="presentation" data-aura-rendered-by="1780:0" data-aura-class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem">
<li class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem" role="presentation" data-aura-rendered-by="1786:0" data-aura-class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem">
<li class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem" role="presentation" data-aura-rendered-by="1792:0" data-aura-class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-aura-rendered-by="1793:0" role="menuitemradio" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" title="Working" aria-checked="false">
<b/>
Working
</a>
</li>
<li class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem" role="presentation" data-aura-rendered-by="1798:0" data-aura-class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem">
<li class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem" role="presentation" data-aura-rendered-by="1804:0" data-aura-class="uiMenuItem uiRadioMenuItem">
<!--render facet: 32:2348;a-->
</ul>
```

I have tried in so many ways including select class and individual xpaths

ex:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='select']")).sendKeys("Working");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='select']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/ul/li[4]/a")).click();
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='select'][@aria-label='Lead Status']")));
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Working");
```

Please help me how can I select list from dropdown without select class.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

First find a xpath which will return you all values of dropdown. Then using List you can select any value.

```
       List<WebElement> myElements = driver.findElements(mySelector);
       for(WebElement e : myElements) {
         if(e.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Your_Desire_Value")) {
             e.click();
         }
```

Note :- click on the dropdown first using simple click operation and then use above code. may you also need to apply focus if value is present in deep below in list

hope it will help you :)